# An energy functional

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $h:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous nondecreasing function and $\gamma$ is a positive continuous function over $\Omega$ such that $0<\gamma(x)<1$ for every $x\in\Omega$, which is a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N\geq 2$. Let $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be the Sobolev space with zero boundary values in the trace sense. Define the functional $I:W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
I(u)=\int_{\Omega}H(u)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
where
$$
H(t)=
\begin{cases}
\int_{0}^{t}h(s)\,s^{-\gamma(x)}\,\mathrm ds,\quad \text{if} \quad t\geq 0,\\
0\quad\text{ if }t<0. 
\end{cases}
$$
Then for every $\phi\in C_c^{1}(\Omega)$, is it true that
$$
\langle I'(u),\phi\rangle=\int_{\Omega}h(u)\,u^{-\gamma(x)}\phi\,\mathrm dx,
$$
where $I^{'}$ is the Gateaux derivative of $I$.

I tried in the following way. Since $h$ is continuous, we have $H^{'}(t)=h(t)t^{-\gamma(x)}$ for every $t\geq 0$ and $H^{'}(t)=0$ for every $t<0$. Then
$$
\langle I^{'}(u),\phi\rangle = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{I(u+t\phi)-I(u)}{t} 
\\=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_{\Omega}\{H(u+t\phi)-H(u)\}\,\mathrm dx}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_{\Omega}\{t\phi H^{'}(u+t\theta\phi)\}\,\mathrm dx}{t}
$$
for some $\theta\in(0,1)$. After this step, I am unable to proceed. Because $u+t\phi$ may have different sign. Can someone please help on how to proceed from here. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you've written this correctly? To specify the Gatuex derivative of a functional you need a two functions as input - a point and a direction. If you look at the wiki article for Gatuex derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) in the example at the end they show that $dI(u ; \phi) = \langle H'(u) , \phi \rangle $ which I think you want to show

Comment: Thanks. Yes, please fix $u$ and $\phi$ and vary $t\to 0$, then I want to see $\langle I^{'}(u),\phi\rangle$ as mentioned.

Comment: Have you looked at the example at the end of the wiki article for the Gatuex derivative? It proves (almost) exactly what you want to prove. If you are still unsure after reading that I can help you out

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have seen it. The example is given for Hilbert space. It seems it will work in this case as well. Still, I am afraid about that, I do not see where the Hilbert space structure is used in the example in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative

Comment: Also, can you please look at the question posed in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265785/constant-for-a-given-limit  Thanks

Comment: Also, the fact that $\gamma$ is a variable does not create a problem and $H^{'}(t)=h(t)t^{-\gamma(x)}$ for $t\geq 0$ and $0$ for $t<0$ seems correct. Kindly inform if this seems fine to you. Thanks. @JackT

Comment: Gateaux, not Gatuex :D